# Como obter os dados digitados no TextBox que foi criados dinamicamente?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Criei alguns controles `TextBox` dinamicamente em meu *Code Behind* e preciso resgatar os valores em um novo método, porém não consigo utilizar o `textbox` alterado em um novo método.

```
        try
        {
            DataTable tbDadosAux =// Método para obter dados;
            DataTable tbDados = //filtra dados

            qtd.Value = tbDados.Rows.Count.ToString();

            table1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            table1.CssClass = ("table table-bordered table-hover table-striped");


            if (tbDados.Rows.Count !=0)
            {
                 tabela1.Visible = true;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < tbDados.Rows.Count; i++)
            {

                TableRow linha = new TableRow();
                TableCell c1 = new TableCell();
                TableCell c2 = new TableCell();
                TableCell c3 = new TableCell();

                Label lblPesNm = new Label();
                TextBox txtSeqNum = new TextBox();
                HiddenField hdPesCodComp = new HiddenField();

                c1.Text = tbDados.Rows[i]["RETORNO"].ToString();
                c1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

                txtSeqNum.ID = "txtSeqNum" + (i + 1);
                txtSeqNum.Text = tbDados.Rows[i]["SEQUENCIAL"].ToString();
                c2.Controls.Add(txtSeqNum);
                c2.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;

                table1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                table1.CssClass = ("table table-bordered table-hover table-striped");

                linha.Cells.Add(c1);
                linha.Cells.Add(c2);


                table1.Rows.Add(linha);
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (tran.Connection != null)
            {
                tran.Rollback();
                conn.Close();
               // Erro.InnerHtml = "Ocorreu o seguinte erro: " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (tran.Connection != null)
            {
                tran.Commit();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Por que não consegue utilizar? Dê mais detalhes.

Comment: Já tentei resgatar assim:
TextBox texto= (TextBox)table1.FindControl("txtSeqNum" + 1);

Comment: E por que isso não dá certo? Ainda não dá pra entender qual o seu problema. Tente ler sua pergunta como alguém que não sabe nada do seu projeto e veja se consegues entender algo.

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Dei um Request.Form[name].

Comment: Você pode até ter conseguido com `Request.Form`, mas, perdeu toda a pagina quebrando o elo principal ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como relatado em seu comentário com `Request.Form` você consegue recuperar, mas, não é a maneira correta para funcionalidades assim, use os componentes como Repeater que são leves e podem trazer muito mais funcionalidades.

A maneira empregada por você na pergunta não vai ter êxito, porque, você não conseguirá persistir o dado dinamicamente assim. Sabe o que acontece na hora que você apertar um botão Submit, esses dados vão sumir (apesar de não ver seu código é um erro curriqueiro), então resolvi criar um exemplo bem simples.

***Exemplo:***

Crie um Repeater assim dentro de um pagina *ASPX*:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
       CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication3.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptDados">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:HiddenField ID="HId" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' runat="server" />
                        <asp:Literal runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Id") %>'></asp:Literal>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TNome" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Nome") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button Text="Enviar" runat="server" OnClick="BtnEnviar_Click"  ID="BtnEnviar" />
        <asp:Label Text="" runat="server" ID="LblResposta" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Observe que no `ItemTemplate` eu tenho os campos que receberão os valores dinâmicamente, ou seja, os item se repetirão conforme a quantidade de elementos que eu vou mandar opelo `DataTable` e o Repeater encarregará de carregar os itens. Após você criar no `Button` **Enviar** ele dispará um evento que vai carregar as modificações nesse `Label` **LblResposta**. Verifique isso no código abaixo:

No código:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {                
                Carregar_Repeater();                
            }
        }

        public void Carregar_Repeater()
        {
            DataTable _DataTable = new DataTable();
            _DataTable.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
            _DataTable.Columns.Add("Nome", typeof(string));

            DataRow _Row = null;
            _Row = _DataTable.NewRow();
            _Row["Id"] = 1;
            _Row["Nome"] = "Nome 1";
            _DataTable.Rows.Add(_Row);

            _Row = _DataTable.NewRow();
            _Row["Id"] = 2;
            _Row["Nome"] = "Nome 2";
            _DataTable.Rows.Add(_Row);


            RptDados.DataSource = _DataTable;
            RptDados.DataBind();
        }

        protected void BtnEnviar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblResposta.Text = string.Empty;
            foreach (RepeaterItem _Item in RptDados.Items)
            {
                HiddenField HId = _Item.FindControl("HId") as HiddenField;
                TextBox TNome = _Item.FindControl("TNome") as TextBox;

                LblResposta.Text += string.Format("<p>{0} {1}</p>", HId.Value, TNome.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

No método *Carregar_Repeater* eu só passo os dados para `DataSource` do `Repeater` e mando carregar os dados para cima (pode ser qualquer tipo de Coleção (`IList`, `ICollection`, etc, mas, no seu caso foi `DataTable`))

Com esse exemplo você conseguirá entender acredito eu o processo em si ...

Answer (score 0):

Existe essa forma que não varre o repeater e vai direto ao linha que o usuario selecionar.

```
protected void Button_Atualizar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    Control botao = (Control)sender; 
    RepeaterItem item =(RepeaterItem)botao.Parent;

    TextBox txt = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox2");
    string titulo = txt.Text;

    TextBox txt1 = (TextBox)item.FindControl("TextBox3");
    string descricao = txt1.Text;

    Label lbl1 = (Label)item.FindControl("Label33");
    string cod_item = lbl1.Text; 
    ...
}
```